# How to set up to use an application on xampp to test api from magento2 installed in Docker?

Tags: docker, api, xampp, localhost, magento2

I have xampp installed set with ports 8081 and ssl to 9001. On xampp I have an application that relies on an api from magento2 (ports 80 and 443) to be populated. This magento2 is installed in docker in my computer, so I would like to be able to test the api locally making these calls from the application on xampp and have the magento2 responding it. This way I would be able to develop and debug both the application on xampp and the magento2 api  in docker. Currently I have both running, but I am missing something on the configuration to have the magento2 to get the requests from the application on xampp. Using insomnia I get the magento2 api on docker to answer properly. Anyone can understand the question and help me with a solution? Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Just had to disable the curl ssl check.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```